# How to run Apache Server and skype together?

Tags: apache-http-server, skype, xampp

I am unable to start apache server while my skype is running. I am using xampp control panel to start apache server.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype sometimes listens on port 443 and Apache wants to listen on port 443 too. 
go in Skype then Tools menu, then options, then advanced and disable use ports 80 & 443.